# Do I get a second chance if I fail the SGX quiz?

Tags: derivatives, regulation, singapore

To trade [Specified Investment Products (SIPs)](https://www.moneysense.gov.sg/articles/2018/11/understanding-specified-investment-products-sips) such futures, options and structured warrants, I need to pass the SGX quiz. What happens if I fail the quiz? Will I get a second chance? What is the maximum number of times I can fail?

Comment: Not an answer because I have no personal experience, but it looks as though you could just sign up with another email address and have another go?